# How can I scale printouts in Google Chrome like Firefox can?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, scaling

Chrome is slowly wooing me from Firefox.

When I print on Firefox, I can have the page print at 80% of normal, and get smaller print and MORE on a page.  When I try that on Google Chrome, I get the same amount of text as if I'd printed at 100% just in a smaller font ... with a lot of whitespace.

Is there a way to make Chrome do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, telling it to print brings up the simplified Print dialog.

If you look at the bottom of it you will see where it says "Print using system dialog... (Ctrl+Shift-P)"

Click on that and you will have access to all the scaling functions that your printer supports, just like in Firefox.

Comment: No, it does not. Those printers that support scaling the printout never repaginate a document. Instead, they produce exactly what the OP says he doesn't want: Finer printouts with white margins. Firefox repaginates a web document.